# Java OpenCV asking for manycam to be open when manycam is already open?

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

So I decided i wanted to learn about image processing and vision tracking and such so installed opencv and got it working in eclipse for Java. However, when i try to take an image all I get is an image that says "Please start Manycam or choose another video source" [image: Here is the image]

Here is the code i am using:

```
package testests;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;

public class Hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture(0);
        if (!cap.isOpened())
            System.out.println("Not connected to webcam ):");
        else
            System.out.println("Connected to camera: " + cap);
        Mat frame = new Mat();
        cap.retrieve(frame);
        System.out.println(frame);
        Highgui.imwrite("test.jpg", frame);
        cap.release();
    }
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

I got it working with manycam. However, i would like to use it without manycam and i cannot figure out how to. each time i try that image comes back up

Answer (score 0):

So to get it working i captured camera index 1 instead of 0. I'm not entirely sure why that worked, but it worked.